# Register WPFToolkit

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dll

How to register WPFToolkit.dll in Windows?, My problem is this: I have an app building in Visual Studio 2012 - WPF with .Net Framework 4.0, when I compile the app, the WPFToolkit.dll is in the Debug Folder, but this app must be in other folder with others .exe, this folder is part of other Application, which loaded the .exes in a Window, the users chose what.exe open, this second application is already installed in windows. When I copy the my app .exe with the WPFToolkit.dll in this folder, the .exe runs succesfull. The .exe find the dll, but when I run my .exe since this second Application, not works. An solution was used GACUTIL, this register the dll in windows system, but GACUTIL is part from SDK, the SDK is only possible install if Visual Studio is installed, But in a Pc without Visual Studio exist GACUTIL, in some blogs explain the GACUTIL is in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL, but not works, I tried this in cmd: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL> gacutil /i yourdll.dll.

Too I tried with regsvr32, but too not works.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) and load the assembly yourself from disk (or from an embedded resource).

Comment: Can you help with specific example?

Answer (score 0):

Exist SDK for Windows 7 y Windows 8, is not necesary have installed Visual Studio, only .NET Framework:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Exist a gacutil.exe where is installed the SDK.